# Ist »geschmeichelt sein« ein korrekter Ausdruck?

Tags: grammaticality, past-participle, grammar-identification

Ist *geschmeichelt sein* – wie im folgenden Ausdruck verwendet – richtiges Deutsch? Um welche grammatikalische Form handelt es sich dabei?

> Ich war geschmeichelt von seinen Worten.

Ich habe bisher nur *sich geschmeichelt fühlen* gehört:

> Ich fühlte mich geschmeichelt von seinen Worten.

Kann man beides verwenden?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nach [Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schmeicheln_%28Konjugation%29) handelt es sich um das Zustandspassiv von schmeicheln: "geschmeichelt sein". Wenn jemand dir schmeichelt, bist du also geschmeichelt. Und fühlst dich vermutlich auch geschmeichelt, aber das ist dann das Adjektiv "geschmeichelt".

Leider finden sich auf Anhieb keine weiteren Belege oder genauere Erklärungen. Mir ist aber auch eher die Form "sich geschmeichelt fühlen" geläufig. In einigen Foren fand sich außerdem, dass viele letztere Form als besser ansehen.

Answer (score 3):

Ob der Ausdruck gültig ist, scheint trivial zu sein: Laut [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schmeicheln) kann man *jemanden schmeicheln* (1.a.). Damit kann man also auch passiv *geschmeichelt sein*. *Geschmeichelt fühlen* fällt unter die gleiche Kategorie.

Comment: Normales Passiv wäre doch "geschmeichelt werden", oder? OregonGhost liegt mit Zustandspassiv wohl richtig.

Comment: @splattne: Meine Antwort sollte nicht implizieren, dass OregonGhosts Antwort falsch ist. Imho ist beides möglich: _geschmeichelt sein_ ist ein Zustand (darum wohl auch "Zustandspassiv"), _geschmeichelt werden_ bedeutet, dass die Aktion des schmeichelns gerade an einem durchgeführt wird.

Comment: klar, mein Kommentar war etwas missverständlich. Danke!

Answer (score 2):

Beides ist möglich. Ich empfinde `fühle mich geschmeichelt` als natürlicher.

Andererseits ist `sein` angebrachter, wenn man sich bei jemandem anderen bedankt (formell und altmodisch):

> Ich bin sehr geschmeichelt, dass Sie sich hierfür die Zeit genommen haben.

Man will schließlich nicht nur sagen, dass man sich momentan `geschmeichelt fühlt`. Der Ausdruck `geschmeichelt sein` ist stärker.